# Machining: Seeking Porting Tool for Milling Female 37deg Flare Ports

Tags: machining, cnc, tools

Been looking for a COTs carbide/ HSS cutting tool for milling standard 37 deg flare fluid ports, but am struggling to find anything applicable. Since these are common enough fluid fittings, I figure there *has* to be something out there.

Does anyone know what this type of tool would be called?

Acceptable specs are either J1926-1 (flare, NOT SAE o-ring boss) or AS5202.
Specifically I'm looking for size -4, 37 deg female AN.

Essentially, I'm interested in a tool that can be used to machine a feature into a part that is similar to this (see photo) in a single in-and-out operation. Thread tapping would happen separately.

Before anyone suggests an adapter... it HAS to be this size and it HAS to be a milled port. So milling an NPT port and installing an adapter unfortunately does not work

[image]

Comment: Before anyone suggests an adapter... it HAS to be this size and it HAS to be a milled port. So milling an NPT port and installing an adapter unfortunately does not work

Comment: please add that info to your question ... it does not belong in a comment

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a shopping question.

Comment: @SolarMike: Why? If someone knows the answer, and it helps me, and doesn't affect anybody else why delete? It is a genuine engineering question because I don't know how these ports are traditionally machined in a mass-manufacturing setting.

Comment: Tn a traditional setting, they are made of 2 parts.  The nut spins separately from the flare.  There is a pressing (or rolling) deformation step involved to make the flare.  A mill may not be the tool you seek

Comment: If you made the nut and tube one part, you likely removed the malleable tube that was to act as a seal and so will need to add a soft metal gasket.

Comment: Interesting point, thanks @Abel. I'm familiar with the female swivel ends, so I see your point